# How many times all my different pages are opened between two given dates(4 days gap),

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Date             Pages
--------       -----------
1-jan-21       PageA-03:15 AM/03:45 AM/04:15AM, PageB-03:20 AM/12:30 PM, PageC-02:14 AM/12:10 PM,
2-jan-21       PageB-01:20 AM/11:30 AM, PageC-05:14 AM/12:10 PM,
5-jan-21       PageA-03:15 AM/03:45 AM/04:15AM, PageC-02:14 AM/12:10 PM,
7-jan-21       PageC-02:14 AM/12:10 PM,
15-jan-21      PageB-01:20 AM/12:30 PM, PageC-05:14 AM/12:10 PM,
16-jan-21              .
   .                   .
   .                   .
   .                   .
   .
list goes ON        list goes ON
```

I am expecting table like this

```
Date           PageA       PageB      PageC
-------      ---------    --------   --------
1-jan-21         3           2         2
2-jan-21         0           2         2
   .
   .
   .
list goes on
```

If i should try REGEXP or without it we can solve using nested query.

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL

Comment: Your data model is poor. Your best move is to fix it, rather than fight it. You may win this battle, but will probably lose the war.

Comment: yes, please can u write and explain the sql query, that would be helpful

Comment: Can you please provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements to replicate some sample data in your table?

Comment: I have alrdy shown the sample data, it wud be enough I guess

Comment: Say I want to try some query to answer you, I have to get your text, edit it, build a table with your data (or something like) and so on. If you would write statementes that create a sample table and populate it with sample data, I would just copy and run them, so it would be easier to try some SQL and help you

Comment: ok, I got u....But if posible create a table anaylisg sample data please- thanx in advnace

Comment: Sorry Aleksej, i dont have it thats y I am requesting u

Answer (score 0):

First I want to echo @Bohemian. your best bet is to clean up this mess of a data model. Each page reference should be a separate row something like:

```
create table page_reference 
                 ( page_ref_id integer generated always as identity
                   ref_date    date
                 , page        varchar2(8)
                 ) ;

-- the query to get the actual data with this is:
select trunc(ref_date), page, count(*) 
  from page_reference
 group by trunc(ref_date), page;
```

I will also venture this could eliminate the code it takes to build this in the first place.  
But, well you can get what you are looking for with jumping through some hoops. First you need to split the comma separated page references then strip off the actual page and count the number of references on each time reference. the main query for that becomes:

```
select *
   --- extract the page referenced and get the number of timestamps for each 
  from ( select the_date
              , substr(page_ref,1, instr(page_ref,'-') -1)   page
              , length(regexp_replace(page_ref, '[^/]')) +1  ref
              
                 --- strip each data element into individual page references
           from ( select the_date,trim(regexp_substr(the_data,'[^,]+', 1, level)) page_ref 
                    from bad_data_model
                  connect by regexp_substr(the_data, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null 
                 ) s1 
        ) s2;
```

Each of the above produce the following:

```
+------------+-------+-----+
|    Date    | Page  | Cnt |
+------------+-------+-----+
| 2021-01-01 | PageB |   2 |
| 2021-01-01 | PageC |   2 |
| 2021-01-01 | PageA |   3 |
| 2021-01-02 | PageB |   2 |
| 2021-01-02 | PageC |   2 |
+------------+-------+-----+
```

There is one last step to arrive at the result you looking for.  The MAIN QUERY needs to be wrapped  is a *SELECT ... PIVOT' structure to generate the desired columnar result from the current row orientated result.

```
select ref_date     "Date"
     , nvl(pagea,0) "PageA"
     , nvl(pageb,0) "PageB"
     , nvl(pagec,0) "PageC" 
  from ( MAIN QUERY here
       )
        -- transform row orientation to column orientation  
 pivot ( max ( case ref when null then 0 else ref end) 
         for (page) 
          in ('PageA' as pagea
             ,'PageB' as pageb  
             ,'PageC' as pagec
             ) 
        ) p1
```

See full [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f48d1b7273606a9f3f36b6f471d84393)